# Может ли оружие быть потомственным?

Tags: выбор-слов, значение-слов, семантика, прилагательные, синонимы

*Может ли оружие быть **потомственным** или только фамильным, родовым?*

Comment: По-видимому, "потомственный" в смысле "наследственный/родовой" является устаревшим значением. И ни для чего, кроме "имения/гнезда", лучше его так не употреблять.

Answer (score 2):

Слово "потомственный" в наше время в подавляющем большинстве случаев используется по отношению к лицу (потомственный дворянин, казак, рабочий и пр.). Впрочем, оно действительно имеет ещё и значение "наследственный/родовой", "передающийся по наследству" в отношении предмета/явления, но сейчас оно считается устаревшим (см. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9)). Поэтому можно порекомендовать использовать "потомственный" в отношении предмета/явления в стилистических целях, и только (см. примеры ниже). А в современной *обыденной* устной и письменной речи делать этого лучше не стоит. Хотя не воспрещается, и примеры тому есть в "Нацкорпусе".

*Кий, Щек и Хорев, создатели городов славенских в полянех, а особливо Киева, как видно из Нестора, были по случаю особливой знатности или храбрости над оными главные повелители, но и тех атасть скончалась без **потомственного наследства**.
(М. В. Ломоносов. Древняя российская история. Фрагменты. 1754–1758)*

*Всегда врал князь Аркадий, как непутевый, однако, по правде сказать, был у меня какой-то прирожденный, **потомственный дар** к лошадям. (А. И. Куприн. Юнкера. 1932)*

*Он сподобился даже по-ломоносовски поступить в консерваторию, дабы не зарывать **потомственный дар** в землю; долго-долго и комично ходил в пыльные классы. (Дарья Симонова. Первый. 2002)*

Comment: Ссылки лучше прятать под словами, иначе выглядит громоздко.